How to protect a docker container with tcp wrappers, xinetd or something like that?
I have a Dicom medical docker container, on a bridged network, that receives tcp connections (not web/http/https) from other Dicom enabled devices, such as MRI scanners. It is an old DCMTK binary modified to work with our DCM solution.
On of our customers wishes to use dns reverse resolutions (PTR records) in order to permit incomming connections that come from a given domain, but no wrapper mechanism is implemented in the container.
Can I use any of the docker native docker mechanisms to accomplish this? I am open to suggestions.
I am thinking into:

Adding tcp wrappers to the container itself.
Run xinet on the host.

None of those is straightforward, hence the question.
